# What Does '技能技术' Mean?

Tags: meaning

Can you please tell me how to translate "提高技能技术".

Both "技能" and "技术" seem to mean skill, but "技术" also means technology.

Comment: poor sentence。It should be 提高技能熟练度 or  提高技术水平。

Comment: sorry, but does that mean they want to raise, improve, 2 things technical ability 技能 AND technology level 技术水平, or should I read 技能技术 as one word, one thing, meaning skill?

Comment: Your understanding is right. They're two things, but close.

Comment: 技术 can also mean technique, or craftsmanship.

Comment: 技术 - technology / technique, 技能 - the ability to apply those technology / technique

Answer (score 1):

From http://wiki.mbalib.com/wiki/%E6%8A%80%E6%9C%AF%E6%8A%80%E8%83%BD , "技術技能" means "technical skill" (.... a typical example of piecemeal translation ....).  "技術" is commonly used as an attributive noun, e.g. "技術人員" (technical staff) and "技術支援" (technical support)

On the other hand, "技術" is seldom used as an attributive noun.

Hence, there are two possibilities:

1) "技能技術" is "技能和技術" with "和" omitted.  Thus, we can translate it as "techniques and skills".

2) It is a typo of "技術技能".  In such case, we should translate it as "technical skills".

Answer (score 0):

I think you can translate it to

```
improve skill level
```

or

```
enhance technical ability
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you play shooting games. Your character has a skill to stun your opponent for 2 seconds. The skill is 技能. You can level up or improve your skill. Now you want to use your skill to take down your opponent. The whole process is measured by your 技术. Your opponent may play better than you when he has a better 技术. Your 技能 may or may not enhance your 技术. To improve your 技术, you'll need a lot of practice.

Back to your question. 提高技能技术 means "level up the skill and improve the proficiency (you may find a better word)".